# TypeError: _jsxDEV is not a function in React-Vite App Using Docker-Compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, vite

**Introduction**: I'm encountering a runtime error when trying to run my React-Vite application using Docker-Compose. The application works perfectly when I use `npm run dev` directly within Docker, but fails with an error when started with `docker-compose up`.

**Environment/Setup**:

- React (Vite-based project)
- Docker and Docker-Compose
- Node.js 16, 18, 20 (all were tested)

Upon starting my application with `docker-compose up`, the application seems to start without issues. However, when I open the page, the console throws the following error:

```
TypeError: _jsxDEV is not a function. (In '_jsxDEV(App, {}, void 0, false, {
        fileName: "/app/src/main.tsx",
        lineNumber: 8,
        columnNumber: 5
    }, this)', '_jsxDEV' is undefined)
```

- This error does not occur when using `docker run -p 5173:5173 my-react-app`, it occurs only when using `docker-compose up frontend`

**What You've Tried**:

- I've made sure all dependencies are correctly installed.
- I've checked for any possible misconfigurations in my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, but everything seems in order.

**Expected vs. Actual Behavior**: I expected the application to run without errors, as it does when started with `docker run` command. However, running it with Docker-Compose results in the mentioned TypeError.

**Code Samples**:

- Dockerfile configuration

```
# Use a Node.js image
FROM node:16

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything to the container
COPY package*.json .

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy everything to the container
COPY . .

# Expose port
EXPOSE 5173

# Start the app from entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

- docker-compose.yml configuration

```
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "5173:5173"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - frontend_build:/app/dist
      - type: bind
        source: ./.env
        target: /app/.env
    env_file:
      - .env
```

- entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" = "development" ]; then
  npm run dev
else
  npm run build
fi
```

- vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true, 
    strictPort: true,
    port: 5173,
  },
})
```

**Additional Context**

Steps to reproduce the error:

- Intialize React App: `npm create vite@latest frontend -- --template react-swc-ts`
- `Dockerfile` should go in `frontend` folder
- `docker-compose.yml` is found in the `parent` folder

**Document Tree**:

```
- parent
| - docker-compose.yml
| - frontend
| | - Dockerfile
| | - vite.config.ts
| | - rest of the app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem has been identified within the `.env` configuration file, where the `NODE_ENV` variable was erroneously set to `production`. For individuals encountering a similar issue, it is recommended to modify the `NODE_ENV` variable to `development` to resolve the problem since vite does not really use this variable for the actual build.